# Best way to do a horizontal scrolling pane in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation

I came up with the solution below. It works great, but I'm curious to know if there's a more efficient way of doing it. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div id="magic-pane" style="width: 300px; height: 400px; background: #eee; overflow: hidden">
    <div id="scroller" style="width: 600px; height: 100%; left: 0px; position: relative">
        <div id="pane1" style="width: 300px; height: 100%; background: #efe; float: left">
            <span id="pane1-clicker">Whee, click me!</span>
        </div>
        <div id="pane2" style="width: 300px; height: 100%; background: #fee; float: left">
            <span id="pane2-clicker">Whoosh! Click me!</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pane1-clicker').click(function() {
        $('#scroller').animate({ left: '-300px' }, 500);
    });
    $('#pane2-clicker').click(function() {
        $('#scroller').animate({ left: '0' }, 500);
    });
});
```

So basically, the magic-pane is a small viewport that's 300px wide. Inside it is a scroller that's twice as wide and contains two divs side-by-side. Pretty simple, but again, just wondering if there's a more efficient way of coding this.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zzUA8/)

Comment: i think `sliding` would be more appropriate than `scrolling`. http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: Its perfect....u can just optimize this with `externel CSS` rather than `inline CSS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the number are minimum, you do not need to worry about anything. Like in you case, 2 is pretty manageable. Note: that you are writing separate `onClick` function for all the pane, which will create problem.

But as the number grow, lets say 50, then you will have to write different onClick functions of `$('#pane1-clicker')` .... `$("#pane50-clicker)`, which is highly inefficient. You should modify your script, to support any number of panes, without writing extra codes.

- Also, extend the function, so that it can be used as plugin.
- It would be better if the plugin could match a particular selector and assign the related positions like `left:300px`

Answer (score 0):

From your current code, the only thing I'd probably change right off the bat is to take out the `$('#scroller')` from the two `click` handlers into a closure. That way, the handlers don't have to select it every single time a click occurs.

```
var $scroller = $('#scroller');
$('#pane1-clicker').click(function() {
    $scroller.animate({ left: '-300px' }, 500);
});
$('#pane2-clicker').click(function() {
    $scroller.animate({ left: '0' }, 500);
});
```